# What's the difference with :(id)sender?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk

What's the difference between declaring a UIButton in Xcode like this:

```
- (IBAction)testButton;
```

and declaring a button like this:

```
- (IBAction)testButton:(id)sender;
```

I understand that in the .m file you would then implement the buttons accordingly, as shown below:

```
- (IBAction)testButton
{
// insert code here..
}
```

and setting it up like this:

```
- (IBAction)testButton:(id)sender
{
// insert code here..
}
```

Is there any additional things you can do by declaring the button with :(id)sender, is there some additional stability, or is there no difference?

Comment: And don't forget the 3rd option: `- (IBAction)testButton:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event`.

Comment: See the docs for `UIControl addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`.

Comment: They are two different methods; one that takes no arguments and one that takes a single argument.  That the framework treats them as the same method is an implementation detail.

Comment: @bbum could you elaborate on the second sentence?

Comment: @JackyBoy The XIB implementation -- the implementation around target/action -- allows the action method to be one of three different forms.  They truly are different methods and which one you choose is dependent on your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With :(id)sender you are able to access the button itself through the sender variable.  This is handy in many situations.  For example, you can have many buttons and give each a tag.  Then use the [sender tag] method to find which button was tapped if many buttons are using this IBAction.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)someMethod:(id)sender {
    // do stuff
}
```

Using `(id)sender`, you have a reference to who sent the method call.  Please note, this doesn't have to be limited to a `UIButton`.

If you're created this method via control-dragging from the storyboard an only hooking up a single button, then `sender` is basically useless (it will always be the same), and should probably be marked as unused:

```
#pragma unused (sender)
```

(The compiler can better optimize your code if you do this.)

However, there's nothing wrong with hooking up several UI elements to the same `IBAction` method.  You can then distinguish the sender via:

```
[sender tag]
```

...which returns an `int` that was either set via the storyboard or programmatically.

Moreover, you can call this method elsewhere in your class.  You can either pass `nil` as the sender, or you can pass it a particular UI element in order to force it into the results you've coded for objects of that tag.

Nonetheless, if you plan to call the method with a `nil` argument, you can always throw:

```
if(!sender)
```

... into the method in order to handle special logic for when the method has been invoked programmatically as opposed to via user interaction.

Comment: As far as I know #pragma unused does not affect the compiled code only silences unused variable warnings, which is not necessary in this case. I would be interested in a link to more information about #pragma unused affecting code generation.

Comment: @Dearden http://nshipster.com/__attribute__/ "Knowing that little bit of context allows the compiler to make optimizations accordingly." (Ctrl+F "unused")  I don't know the details of it, but I do tend to trust stuff from `NSHipster`.

Comment: Thank you for the link to NSHipster. I was intrigued earlier but testing showed no difference in the assembly language by marking variables as unused. I believe LLVM is smart enough to not need the pointer, at least under ARC.

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to know which button you are working with. I have posted a simple example for a card game below

```
- (IBAction)flipCard:(id)sender {
    [self.game flipCardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:sender]];
    self.flipCount++;
    [self updateUI];
}
```

This method is used for a card flipping game. There are multiple buttons on the screen representing different cards. When you hit the button, a card in the model must be flipped. We know which one by finding the index of the variable `sender`

Comment: It'd `id`, not `UIButton`.

Comment: @nhgrif  Either id or UIButton is fine.  id is the general type for all objects, UIButton is just more specific.  Hierarchy, my friend :)

Comment: I understand, but `IB` gives you `id`, and it's better to use `id` in this case.

Comment: Why is that?  UIButton can make the code more readable.  In the end, it's a UIButton in any case.  The only reason I could see using id is for code re-use

Comment: It's not "a UIButton in any case".  That's why.

Comment: I think I deserve an upvote for you guys blowing up my inbox :p

Comment: @nhgrif If he knows it's a UIButton then it's better coding to use a UIButton. IB will warn should a user then link something other than a UIButton to the action and errors can be spotted earlier since the code might rely on the sender responding to a UIButton action. In my opinion, best practice is to avoid using the generic id as much as possible.

Comment: @Dearden Your argument, by extension then says, a method which only one button should be hooked, or for which every button hooked into it should call the same logic, should even take an argument at all.  The problem here is that means if in the future, I decide to treat `buttonA` slightly different from `buttonB`, then I either need a whole new method, or I have to rewrite this one, including fixing all the `IB` hook-ups.  The same applies for `UIButton*` versus `id`, if in the future I do decide I want to hook up a text field's value changed to do the same logic, I have either write a new

Comment: method and duplicate code (which is just bad), or I have to rewrite this method in such a way that means going through `IB` and fixing all the hook-ups.  Anyway, @JoshEngelsma I will upvote if the answer is changed to `id`, but perhaps you can convince one of the others who think `UIButton*` is fine to upvote you.

Comment: My set of rules: 1. If the method relies on the sender being of a certain type, then it should be declared as such. 2. However, it's always better to use isKindOfClass: or respondsToSelector: to conditional call the object methods. 3. Best, avoid using sender at all. Using id means a crash at runtime when you call a UIButton method without the benefit of a warning from the compiler or a kind reminder to the coder of the need for a UIButton. As for the code posted by Josh, the type is irrelevant for sender is never sent a message, and hence I concur – should be id for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, @nhgrif it seems that your point has been taken :) I have updated my answer to reflect the changes